# How to Test the Graph API app with users that do not have Timeline enabled?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I have created some users to test an application that uses Open Graph Beta (with custom actions and objects), but it's not possible to switch them accounts to the new Timeline, so it's not possible to use them for testing

How could test the app with these accounts?

Comment: why not you test on your account first 
normally i check app on my account first than allow other

Answer (score 1):

It **is** possible to activate timeline for those users, go to https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline - it may take a few minutes after the test user is created before the activate timeline link will work

Comment: I created the user yesterday but there is no activation link in that page